# Call for a definite value from an async method in flutter. waiting problem

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await

How to write a function which fetches value from an async method ?

Future FetchValuefromService(String tk) async{ await .. //Fetch from api return value; }

void mainfunction(){ double newval =FetchValuefromService('hello'); //.... do something with newval. }

if i make mainfunction() async then the "do something" in mainfucntion will not get the double value. I need to get newval from service and then only i need to proceed.

Comment: There's never a way to turn an async value into a sync value in other than an async fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Making a function `async` ables to use the `await` keyword in its body. Place it to the left of a `Future<T>` expression to pause the execution until the `Future` completes and the `T` value is obtained.

In your case, it would be `double newval = await FetchValuefromService('hello');`